# How to turn pandas series into a matrix?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, matrix

I have the below series and would like to turn it into a matrix with the Index column split into individual letters.

I am unsure of the easiest way to generate the matrix would anyone be able to help with how to do this?

Series:

```
A-B    10
A-C    20
A-D    30
B-C    40
B-D    50
C-D    60
```

Desired:

```
    A   B   C   D
A   1  10  20  30
B  10   1  40  50
C  20  40   1  60
D  30  50  60   1
```

I have split out the index of the series into unique values with the following:

```
set([item for sublist in [i.split('-') for i in df.index.tolist()] for item in sublist])
```

Sample data:

```
df = pd.Series([10,20,30,40,50,60],index=["A-B","A-C","A-D","B-C","B-D","C-D"])

pd.DataFrame([[1,10,20,30],[10,1,40,50],[20,40,1,60],[30,50,60,1]],index = ["A","B", "C", "D"], columns = ["A","B", "C", "D"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you got

```
sr = pd.Series([10,20,30,40,50,60],index=["A-B","A-C","A-D","B-C","B-D","C-D"])
```

you can reset the series index to get a DataFrame and rename the columns

```
df = sr.reset_index()
df.columns = ['row_col', 'data']
```

that gives

```
  row_col  data
0     A-B    10
1     A-C    20
2     A-D    30
3     B-C    40
4     B-D    50
5     C-D    60
```

Now, complete missing combinations

```
df_inv = pd.DataFrame({
    'row_col': df.row_col.str[::-1],
    'data': df.data
})
df_values = df.append(df_inv)
```

yielding

```
  row_col  data
0     A-B    10
1     A-C    20
2     A-D    30
3     B-C    40
4     B-D    50
5     C-D    60
0     B-A    10
1     C-A    20
2     D-A    30
3     C-B    40
4     D-B    50
5     D-C    60
```

Now you can split the `row_col` column with `expand` into two new columns

```
df_values[['row', 'col']] = df_values.row_col.str.split('-', 1, expand=True)
```

and we get

```
  row_col  data row col
0     A-B    10   A   B
1     A-C    20   A   C
2     A-D    30   A   D
3     B-C    40   B   C
4     B-D    50   B   D
5     C-D    60   C   D
0     B-A    10   B   A
1     C-A    20   C   A
2     D-A    30   D   A
3     C-B    40   C   B
4     D-B    50   D   B
5     D-C    60   D   C
```

Finally, we can `pivot` to get "matrix" (pivot table)

```
df_piv = df_values[['row', 'col', 'data']].pivot(
    index='row', columns='col'
).fillna(1).astype(int)
```

and we get the wanted table

```
    data            
col    A   B   C   D
row                 
A      1  10  20  30
B     10   1  40  50
C     20  40   1  60
D     30  50  60   1
```

Answer (score 0):

At the top of my solution, I did two imports

```
import pandas as pd
import string
```

Instead of putting the indices and values into a series, I put them into lists

```py
index = ["A-B","A-C","A-D","B-C","B-D","C-D"]
values = [10,20,30,40,50,60]
```

We can initialize two empty arrays in which to store our numeric indices. I mapped the letters to their numeric equivalent starting the index at `0` so we can populate a matrix easily. So `A=0`, `B=1`, `C=2`, etc.

```py
x = []
y = []
for idx in index:
    split = idx.split("-")
    x.append(string.ascii_lowercase.index(split[0].lower()))
    y.append(string.ascii_lowercase.index(split[1].lower()))
```

To get the other combinations, I just double the `values` list, and append `x` and `y` to `y` and `x`, respectively.

```py
values = [10,20,30,40,50,60] *2
x_copy = x
x = x + y
y = y + x_copy
```

Now, I create my `final` matrix, which is 4*4 and has the default value of `1`. Looping through each value in the `values` list, I populate the `final` matrix by assigning values to `final[i][j]`.

```py
final = [[1]*4 for _ in range(4)]
for i in range(len(values)):
    final[x[i]][y[i]] = values[i]
```

Now, I create a list of column/index names, `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']` and initialize my DataFrame.

```py
names = [chr(ord('@')+1+x) for x in range(4)]
df = pd.DataFrame(final, columns=names, index=names)
```

This is my final output
[image: df image]